# Search Value Firebase Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to access a key with unknown parent as :

```
var ref = admin.database().ref("user_contacts/{pushId}").child(event.data.ref.parent.key);
              ref.once("value", function(querySnapshot) {
                      var qVal = querySnapshot.val();
                console.log("Query Value:", qVal);
       });
```

Snapshot always return null, data exists for this key under multiple.

```
{pushId}  //push ids are unknown here.
```

I also tried this:

```
var ref = admin.database().ref("user_contacts/{pushId}").orderByChild(snapshot.ref.parent.key);
              ref.once("value", function(querySnapshot) {
                      var qVal = querySnapshot.val();
                console.log("Query Value:", qVal);
       });
```

but same response.

Is there any else way to achieve this? Or any body here can suggest an improvement in my method? I am just trying to search a key in the database.

Comment: kindly post Your JSON.?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Now I had to change my structure for querying as I needed task to be completed asap. :)

Comment: Maybe you dnt have to if you post Your JSON.!